# jQuery .load( ) Wordpress content to Div -Not working on other computers-

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I asked a question last week about loading wordpress content into a div using jQuery - it worked like a charm.  I have it styled, loading well on my computer and my phone HOWEVER, it does not load on anyone else's machine.  I can't figure out why.  Will someone please take a look with fresh eyes?  Thank you very much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <title>untitled</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="myblog">
        <p>Loading...</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myblog").load("http://www.zephyrdesigns.com/blog/index.php #content");
});
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why would it load correctly on my machine?  Is it because I have jQuery installed on my machine?  Why does it load correctly on my phone?  Why will it not load elsewhere?

Final issue: the blog post is at http://www.zephyrdesigns.com/blog (according to the address bar) but I assume the index.php file is where the items are sourced (and it does work on my local site [uploaded of course to allow ajax commands to work in jQuery).  Does .php work differently in that regard?  Am I grabbing the wrong .php file?

Comment: Sorry, by installed I just meant I downloaded the library and had it in my hard drive.  I also originally linked to my own uploaded jQuery library file but read that it is better to use the Google link for better load times, caching, etc.

Comment: Are you sure that #content always exists in the index.php?

Comment: I don't have a firm grasp of .php.  I know that I got this working (and it still works) using the index.php link and specifying #content but it seems there is a fluidity to .php.  I have tried to research this info and spoke with one fairly knowledge guy, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

When you make this request, your web server returns "301 Moved Permanently" error, tested with Firebug in Mozilla Firefox. Maybe hot linking is disabled by your server settings?

Comment: I saw that.  Any idea why it works "locally" (even though it is supposedly processing server-side)?

Comment: I have tried to load this URL: http://www.zephyrdesigns.com/blog/?p=20,
it does not show this 301 error, but still I got no HTML response...

Comment: Thank you for trying.  The reason I was using the front page was because it dynamically displays the last 5 posts and will constantly update.  Still, I'd rather have anything working than nothing!

Comment: So it is working for me here on my end as long as the user types in <<"http://www.zephyrdesigns.com">>and NOT just <<"zephyrdesigns.com">>.  Can anyone duplicate that on their end?  It seems there is a disagreement between "www" and the lack thereof.  I believe I can modify the .htaccess file to modify what users type in their address bar, right?

Comment: The above comment is a mess.  I'm sorry.  I had to create an .htcaccess file redirecting all my "zephyrdesigns.com" to include the "www" and it seems to have solved the issue.  There was, in fact, a disagreement between "www" and non-"www" domains as had been suggested.